# change default marker mapbox on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, mapbox, marker

I need your lights, I would like when clicking on the default marker mapboxgl to be replaced by a png marker, I tried this code but it doesn't work. I don't know if it's the good way.. Thanks for your help

```js
   var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({color:'orange',className:'marker1'}) 
  .setLngLat([2.5,42.5])
  .addTo(map);
  
   $('.marker1').click(function(event){ 
  var el = document.createElement('div');   
   el.id = 'pinOrange';
   el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/img/pinOrange.png")';
   el.style.width = '5px';
   el.style.height = '5px';
   
   new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset:[-25, -25]})
   .setLngLat([2.5,42.5])
   .addTo(map);
  
    if ((".marker1").show()){ 
    ((".marker1").hide())
    (("#pinOrange").show())
    } else if (("#pinOrange").show()){
    (("#pinOrange").hide())
    ((".marker1").show())
    }
  });
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined" is the error message on your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you took your code from https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

The modifications you have applied work. I have replaced your image by the image given in the mapbox example.

It works only with Bitmap format. PNG is not supported. When using a Bitmap this is not a problem!

The below code uses a bitmap image, that is why it works.

```js
      var el = document.createElement('div');   
   el.id = 'pinOrange';
   el.style.backgroundImage =
            'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' +
            marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') +
            '/)';
   el.style.width = '5px';
   el.style.height = '5px';
   
   new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset:[-25, -25]})
   .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
   .addTo(map);
      
      
    });
```